# WordPress Post Revisions

Tags: wordpress, revisions

Ok relatively simple question here. I just want to display the autosaves/revisions on my Edit Post page so my client can alternate between old autosaves etc.

Any ideas how i turn this on ?

Thanks!!!

**** EDIT: ANSWERED

On Edit Post page i simply clicked at the top "Screen Options" to show the Post Revisions Module. I didn't realise how simple it was!

[image: Enabling Post Revisions Module]

Comment: add this as an answer & accept it. someone might mistake this for an unanswererd question... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a short while i was able to fix the issue. Simply see the Edit i made to the question itself. thanks!

Comment: Matt, you should put the answer here in your answer. If you do, I'll vote it up.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add here my solution.
I had relatively same problem (cpt posts don't show revisions meta-box or checkbox in screen options DESPITE multiple edits).

For my problem I had to dig deep into living project, touched by many devs before me.

The answer was found by me in databse - 'revisions' are stored as childres posts to the cpt posts they belong to. That means they are themselves a post_type.
That also means, that they identify their parent by value in column 'post_parent' - where the ID of a post sits.

There was a custom function in my project for overwriting post_parent for custom posts (mainly for the purpose of custom breadcrumbs). It was also overwriting revisions post_parent values for some reason.

I've simply added `$post->post_type != 'revision'`
to parameters of function and then

```
if($post->post_type != 'revision') {
        $data['post_parent'] = $post->ID;
    }
```

just to be sure.

I hope it'll help at least one person, desperately looking for answer like I did today.